# View controller navigation / transition through POP UP action button (UIAlertAction)

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, popup

Following are the lines of code that I am using in swift (Xcode) for creating a pop up.

```
//create the alert

let alert=UIAlertController(title: "Better Luck Next Time", message: "Try Again Later", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

// add an action (button)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

// show the alert
self.presentViewController(alert,
                           animated: true,
                           completion: nil)
```

Once the user presses the OK button in the pop up menu; I want the app to navigate to another view controller. I know that I have to put some lines of code in the handler part of UIAlertAction. But I am not sure of how to code this transition. Any one has any simple and effective ideas ??.

Answer (score 0):

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Default AlertController", message: "A standard alert", preferredStyle: .Alert)

            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
                println("you have pressed the Cancel button");
            }
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

            let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
                println("you have pressed OK button");
                if let navController = self.navigationController
                {
                          navController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
                }
            }
            alertController.addAction(OKAction)


            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
```